# Jobs Per Unit Output

Tags: macroeconomics

I am trying to follow a report from the World Bank titled "Issues in estimating the employment
generated by energy sector activities", which can be found here: https://openknowledge.worldbank.org/handle/10986/16969 .

In Appendix 2 Part 4 shown below, the author(s) tells that jobs per unit output is derived from census data using average wage rates and the number of employees in the industry. However, they do not list the exact formula/equation to get jobs per unit output. I was wondering if someone could provide clarification on how this is done.

[image]